# Expiration of accountId in Rest API

Tags: rest, docusignapi

Before first sending signing request I should get a accountId.
So is there any expiration time for this accountID? Can I save it and use it any time with unlimited time if there is no changes in credential or/and other api key and so on?

I can't find information about strategy for accountId in rest api documentation.

Thank you

ref:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/request-a-signature-via-email
https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST API References/Login.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The account ID is part of your developer account. You can find it when you login by clicking on the little down arrow in the top right corner next to your avatar.  It will display your name the name of the company then a number.  That is the account ID.

The account ID does not expire.  The way DocuSign manages access to the API's is through an Integrator key.  For information about the Integrator key please refer to the following link.  https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview

So from a broad overview you would want to break up the different business processes by business group and have a different Integrator Key for each unit.  That way if someone builds bad code or something strange happens and they turn of one of the Integrator keys it does not affect every group in the company.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expiration of your `accountId` however note that it will change between environments - i.e. when you move from demo to production.  Therefore the best practice is to write your integration such that, for a given user, it makes the login call then uses the `accountId` returned from that in subsequent API requests.  By writing it this way you also make the go live process easier since you wouldn't have to remember to go back and change any hard-coded values in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Note that when you are in production, your organization (or your customers' organizations) may well have more than one account id. And that individuals within the organization may well have access to more than one account.

Example: a company has different rules for electronic signature requests that are sent from the legal department and all the other corporate departments. Depending on the differences in the rules, the best DocuSign configuration may be to establish two different accounts, one for legal and one for everybody else. And some people may have access to both accounts.

Bottom line: when your API integration app logs in, it should enable either the human or your config file to specify the account that should be used (if the user has access to more than one account.) While all users have a "default account," it is not always the case that the default is the one that should be used by your integration.